# Mocking default exported function with Jest says it wasn't called but it was

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, react-native, jestjs

**[EDIT - POSSIBLE SOLUTION]**

So I realised that my componentWillMount is an async method since it is using an async fs wrapper to do fs operations. So I made the `beforeEach` function argument `async` and `await`ed on the `Enzyme.shallow`. This seems to have worked. It just came to me that if it's async maybe the lifecycle hadn't run yet when the expectation was ran... What do you think?
It now looks like this

```
// root/Meetings/__tests__/MeetingsScreen.test.js
...
import sortMeetings from '../../helpers/sort';
jest.mock('../../helpers/sort', () => jest.fn());

describe('MeetingsScreen', () => {
  let wrapper;
  const mockValueForMeetings = [];
  sortMeetings.mockReturnValue(mockValueForMeetings);

  beforeEach(async () => {
    wrapper = await Enzyme.shallow(<MeetingsScreen />);
  });

  it('should call the sort method', () => {
    expect(sortMeetings).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

**[ORIGINAL QUESTION]**

I am mocking an imported function and the test says that it wasn't called but it returns the stubbed value.

I have this class/screen in react-native that imports a helper file that only has one function to do a sort.

```
// root/helpers/sort.js
import moment from 'moment';

const compareDateTime = (a, b) => {
  ...
};

const sortMeetings = meetings => meetings.sort(compareDateTime);

export default sortMeetings;
```

My class looks like this

```
// root/Meetings/MeetingsScreen.js
...
import sortMeetings from '../helpers/sort';


export default class MeetingsScreen extends Component {
  ...

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateState();
  }

  updateState = async () => {
    const meetingsOnFile = await fsStorage.getItem('meetings'); // this is also stubbed and returns an [{}]
    const meetings = sortMeetings(meetingsOnFile);
    this.setState({ meetings });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MeetingList meetings={this.state.meetings} />
    );
  }
}
```

And this it my test. I am using Jest.

```
// root/Meetings/__tests__/MeetingsScreen.test.js
...
import sortMeetings from '../../helpers/sort';
jest.mock('../../helpers/sort', () => jest.fn());

describe('MeetingsScreen', () => {
  let wrapper;
  const mockValueForMeetings = [];
  sortMeetings.mockReturnValue(mockValueForMeetings);

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = Enzyme.shallow(<MeetingsScreen />);
  });

  it('should call the sort method', () => {
    expect(sortMeetings).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

So If I got it right, since the import of the default function returns a function when using Jest i am mocking with a function. Before the test I am setting that mock to always return an empty array and I am printing out down the code after the call of the function (in the source code) and it indeed returns an array. I changed it to others values as well (i.e. 13, [2, 3, 4], et.c) and they all get returned. So I would assume that the mock function gets called. But the expectation fails. If I print the `sortMeetings.mock` as well, it just shows empty arrays in it's values `{"calls":[],"instances":[],"timestamps":[]}`

Could someone point to the mistake I am doing. I think I might be wrong about how import default functions work or how Jest is doing the mocking